# Predicate quandary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I want to modify some Core Data entities via a `for in` loop. The fetched objects should be filtered via a predicate. But the loop never fires because no objects are fetched.

I suspect there's an issue with the predicate, although I've vetted it pretty closely. Here's the code:

```
NSString *replenishString = @"Replenishment";
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSPredicate *transFRCPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(account == %@) AND ((transDate >= %@) AND (transDate <= %@)) AND (category != %@)",self.detailTransaction.account,self.detailTransaction.transDate,now,replenishString];


NSFetchedResultsController *transactionsToAdjustFRC = [WMMGTransaction MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:@"account" withPredicate:transFRCPredicate sortedBy:@"transDate" ascending:NO];

(...)

    for (WMMGTransaction *transaction in transactionsToAdjustFRC.fetchedObjects)
    {
        NSLog(@"Inside for loop--delta = %@",delta);
        transaction.category = @"Changed +";

        transaction.pointBalance = [transaction.pointBalance decimalNumberByAdding: delta];
        NSLog(@"Inside for loop--pointBalance = %@",transaction.pointBalance);
    }
```

Any ideas or guidance?

Thanx!

Comment: are you expecting category != %@ (replenishString) to be case sensitive? A direct string comparison using = or != assumes an exact match.

Comment: Currently, there are only two possibilities: nil or Replenishment, so yes, exact match...

Comment: Print out the predicate and post the result here.

Comment: take each part of the predicate out and test as you add them in individually and then progressively together - when does it stop returning what you expect ?

Comment: you can actually remove this inBetween comparison of dates just use > self.detailTransaction.transDate.

Comment: Ok, the problem is with the (category != %@) part. But not sure why...

Comment: Is the category nil?  If so, you need to explicitly test for it: "...(category != %@ OR category == nil)...".

Comment: Ok, solved! I used Wain's method and @pbasdf's addition of the test for nil. If you guys would like to put your responses in an answer, I'll be happy to up vote both. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take care when using "!=" in predicates: a nil value will not match.  Include a specific test for nil:

```
NSPredicate *transFRCPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(account == %@) AND ((transDate >= %@) AND (transDate <= %@)) AND (category != %@ OR category == nil)",self.detailTransaction.account,self.detailTransaction.transDate,now,replenishString];
```